# Airflow task to refer to multiple previous tasks?

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

Is there a way I can have a task require the completion of multiple upstream tasks which are still able to finish independently?

- **download_fcr** --> **process_fcr** --> **load_fcr**
- **download_survey** --> **process_survey** --> **load_survey**

**create_dashboard** should require load_fcr and load_survey to successfully complete.

I do not want to force anything in the 'survey' task chain to require anything from the 'fcr' task chain to complete. I want them to process in parallel and still complete even if one fails. However, the dashboard task requires both to finish loading to the database before it should start.

```
fcr *-->*-->*
             \
               ---> create_dashboard
                /
survey *-->*-->*
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
download_fcr.set_downstream(process_fcr)
process_fcr.set_downstream(load_fcr)

download_survey.set_downstream(process_survey)
process_survey.set_downstream(load_survey)

load_survey.set_downstream(create_dashboard)
load_fcr.set_downstream(create_dashboard)
```

Comment: Can I instead use upstream to define all the dependencies?
process_fcr.set_upstream(download_fcr)

Answer (score 8):

You can pass a **list of tasks** to set_upstream or set_downstream. In your case, if you specifically want to use set_upstream, you could describe your dependencies as:

```
create_dashboard.set_upstream([load_fcr, load_survey])

load_fcr.set_upstream(process_fcr)
process_fcr.set_upstream(download_fcr)

load_survey.set_upstream(process_survey)
process_survey.set_upstream(download_survey)
```

Have a look at [airflow's source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/5646d31154956d8644329d0a1ef44cedbb0d27f5/airflow/models.py#L2940): even when you pass just one task object to set_upstream, it actually wraps a list around it before doing anything.